# Why would Android Tools fastboot NOT recognize a device, but ADB does?

Tags: android, fastboot

On Nvidia ShieldTV Android Tools fastboot NOT recognizing a device, but ADB does?

Trying to execute Fastboot commands from windows PC to a Nvidia Shield TV via USB. I am having issues on windows 10 getting fastboot to recognize shield TV. Wondering if anyone has advice on troubleshooting this.

ADB has no issues

- shows the device when I run "adb devices"
- I can "adb reboot bootloader" and/or "adb reboot fastboot" with out any issues
- I did UNLOCK the boot loader from the appropriate screen

after the adb reboot when I enter the screen where I believe I should be running fastboot ( from the menu that displays "boot recovery kernal", "unlock bootloader", etc.. ) The command "fastboot devices" returns empty and running the commands to install the new image just returns fastboot "< waiting for any device >"

Am I missing a step? Why would adb work and fastboot not?

Some other notes

- Shield TV did prompt me to accept my windows PC for USB and Network connectivity.
- I attempted the same thing with a Linux machine but in that case the ShieldTV never prompted me to allow my Linux device to connect so adb is stuck with an unauthorized for the device.

Comment: Do you install the USB driver? https://developer.nvidia.com/gameworksdownload#?search=SHIELD%20Family%20Windows%20USB

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Having issues Installing TWRP Recovery On Huawei Mediapad T3 10 from Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/1669444/having-issues-installing-twrp-recovery-on-huawei-mediapad-t3-10-from-windows)